# AspectJ Load time weaving fails in AWS SWF using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I added Default VM argument at Installed jre

**-javaagent:E:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\aws-java-sdk\aspectj-1.7.3.jar**

Followed instrucion from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html#swf-flow-prereq)

But Still Getting Below Error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in E:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\aws-java-sdk\aspectj-1.7.3.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Now, I included the the path as per document provided by AWS which is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html)

Need to change this path to **aspectjweaver.jar** which is inside **aspectj-1.7.3\lib**

Now My New path is

```
-javaagent:"E:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\aws-java-sdk\aspectj-1.7.3\lib\aspectjweaver.jar"
```

and now working

```
[AppClassLoader@4f1799e7] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.6.12 built on Tuesday Oct 18, 2011 at 17:52:06 GMT
[AppClassLoader@4f1799e7] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4f1799e7
[AppClassLoader@4f1799e7] info using configuration /F:/AWS%20Workspace/HelloWorldWeb/build/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@4f1799e7] info register aspect com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.aspectj.AsynchronousAspect
[AppClassLoader@4f1799e7] info register aspect com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.aspectj.ExponentialRetryAspect
```

and also include  **aspectj-1.7.3.jar**

1. Click Project **Properties**.
2. Click **AspectJ Build** and then click the **Aspect Path** tab.
3. Click **Add External JARs**.

Jar is at location

```
E:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\aws-java-sdk\aspectj-1.7.3.jar
```