# SWF workflow using @Asynchronous fails even after using aspectj plugins and other dependencies

Tags: aspectj, amazon-swf, aspectj-maven-plugin

Here is my sample workflow implementation:

```
public class GreeterWorkflowImpl implements GreeterWorkflow {
    private helloWorld.HelloWorldWorkflow.GreeterActivitiesClient operations = new helloWorld.HelloWorldWorkflow.GreeterActivitiesClientImpl();

    public void greet() {
        Promise<String> name = operations.getName();
        Promise<String> greeting = operations.getGreeting(name);

        sayMore(greeting);

        //operations.say(greeting);
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void sayMore(Promise<String> greeting) {
        System.out.println(greeting.get()+ " 8.0");
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

Workflow execution failed

```
        ["java.lang.IllegalStateException",{"cause":null,"stackTrace":[{"methodName":"get","fileName":"Settable.java","lineNumber":91,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.core.Settable","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"get","fileName":"Functor.java","lineNumber":35,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.core.Functor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"sayMore","fileName":"GreeterWorkflowImpl.java","lineNumber":23,"className":"helloWorld.HelloWorldWorkflow.GreeterWorkflowImpl","nativeMethod":false},
    {"methodName":"greet","fileName":"GreeterWorkflowImpl.java","lineNumber":16,"className":"helloWorld.HelloWorldWorkflow.GreeterWorkflowImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke0","fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":-2,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":true},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":62,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":43,"className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"Method.java","lineNumber":498,"className":"java.lang.reflect.Method","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invokeMethod","fileName":"POJOWorkflowDefinition.java","lineNumber":150,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"access$1","fileName":"POJOWorkflowDefinition.java","lineNumber":148,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doTry","fileName":"POJOWorkflowDefinition.java","lineNumber":76,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition$1","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"","fileName":"","lineNumber":0,"className":"--- continuation
---","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"POJOWorkflowDefinition.java","lineNumber":66,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"doAsync","fileName":"AsyncDecider.java","lineNumber":70,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider$WorkflowExecuteAsyncScope","nativeMethod":false}],"localizedMessage":"not ready","message":"not ready","suppressed":["[Ljava.lang.Throwable;",[]]}]
```

---

I have followed the answer from this (used aspectjrt and aspectj-maven-plugin).

[AspectJ Load time weaving fails in AWS SWF using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269591/aspectj-load-time-weaving-fails-in-aws-swf-using-java)

Comment: The stack trace clearly indicates that @Asynchronous was ignored. So there is still something wrong with AspectJ setup.

Comment: I was unable to find the issue in aspectj setup. Luckily I stumbled upon this link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=534715&#534715 which suggests to use Task which achieves the functionality of asynchronous without using aspectj. Working fine now, will understand aspectj sometime later.

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392655/how-to-consume-amazon-swf/28843218#28843218 and https://github.com/mirceal/swf-flow-java18-sample